# difference between tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model and tff.learning.from_keras_model

Tags: tensorflow-federated

In federated learning task, I found those two method:

```
def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)
```

and

```
def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch, loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
```

I would like to know which is better  and if it can influence on result (accuracy, loss) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model` has been deprecated and removed from the API a while ago in v0.13.0. See [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/d878ef914b9f43343afc429b28ce219ce4fecd69) for more info.

I highly recommend updating your TFF version.

Comment: Hi, what should we use instead of "tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model". I have a code of last year and I am now got an error because of this issue. I used the last version of TFF and then I also tried with: tensorflow version 2.2.0 and tensorflow_federated version 0.14.0. But it still do not work. @Jakub Konecny

Comment: Use `tff.learning.from_keras_model`. Does this part of TFF tutorial help? The change should be straightforward. https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification#creating_a_model_with_keras

Comment: Thank you for your response @Jakub Konecny. I had `return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)` in the previous version and in the link that you send the equivalent of it is `return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])` I think, input_spec is my sample_batch here, therefore I replace `input_spec=preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec` with `input_spec=sample_batch`

Comment: (cont.) and run the code in colab. It generates me this error: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py", line 92, in from_keras_model
    raise ValueError('`keras_model` must not be compiled')
ValueError: `keras_model` must not be compiled` The error message is not clear to me. I search on google but I could not find any answer. Do you have an idea on this? Thank you.